# Is there a way to have the console close automatically after a user inputs my restraints of an "Incorrect" answer in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++

Im new to c++ and just started my first class last week. Im doing all my c++ programming in Visual Studio. My program states that a user type in an integer from 1 to 15. They have two attempts and if they fail to enter in an integer between these number the program exits. If they do type in an integer from 1 to 15, itll sum up all the integers from zero to that number and the program completes.

My question is, is it possible to have the console window completely exit after the failed attempt yet continue to stay open when the user gets it right even though the program is finished and you just have to press any key to exit? The console window stays open for both outcomes obviously the program will run its course and the console will debug and you have to press any key to exit which ever the outcome. Of course the right answer will give you additional information.

Im trying to emphasize the error/incorrect portion of the assignment by having the console window completely exit. Is this stupid? Possible? or is having the debugging prompt enough to show the program has exited?

Thanks again for anyone who can offer some feedback!

Comment: The console window staying open or closing depends on how you run your program. If you run through the debugger, the window will close immediately once the program exits. If you run outside of the debugger the window will stay open after program exit. If you run from the Explorer then the window will also close once the program exits, and if you run in an open command-line window then it won't be closed.

Comment: When the console is opened or closed is in your case the responsibility of the IDE - VisualStudio. Please, note: Older versions of VS closed the console automatically when debugging ended. That was annoying as you hadn't time to read the error messages. Recent versions keep the console open (and re-use it for next debugging) what I personally appreciate. For a regular application, you wouldn't assume it to run in VS. Instead, you would call it from Explorer or Start menu. In this case, the console will be usually closed when the appl. exited.

Comment: As for solving your problem, for keeping the window open why not simply ask the user to input a line, and then read it? Because the program is waiting for input it won't exit, and the window won't be closed. And for the "incorrect" answer, just exit the program (but note that it might not actually close the window, as it's controlled by external factors as mentioned above).